# how to create an APK in my application programaticly?

Tags: android, apktool

let me explain the situation :
there are two apps coming from two individual android studio projects :

**1** . an app which be installed in the users device and the user use it to make the **2** app

**2** . an app which is to be created in the 1 app . there is just one variable (lets call it **X**) which should be selected by the user (which will be selected in **1**) and make an specific APK file of this (**2**) project .

eg: user installs the **1** app and opens it . then selects number 5 for the variable **X** and presses the button (MakeTheApk) and finally gets his 5.apk which is coded in the **2** project and **X**=5 is in it . 
like so another user may select 7 for the variable **X** .

I don't know is that possible or not . so I will be happy if you are experienced and say me *it't impossible man !*

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how because I haven't attempted something before, but I can say that it is possible. There are apps on the app store that let you make other apps in them.

Comment: no body ? what does it mean ? no one knows the answer ? what should I do now ?